# Setting the background color of UINavigationBar has no effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

For most iOS widgets I can set the background color. It appears that UINavigationBar is not this way.
Furthermore I cannot set the navigation item (top item)'s background as it does not respond to setBackgroundColor.

How can I change that color?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `setTintColor:` instead:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Change it by following code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use the Interface Builder:

[image: UINavigationBar Properties]