# How to set Slidenavigationcontroller naviagtion bar color?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios8.4, uibackgroundcolor

I'm working on iOS app with slidenavigationcontroller, I integrated the viewcontroller for the side menu and everything works fine.But the navigationbar background color not changing.The code I used to set background color for navigation bar background.

```
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

It shows color as hidden as below

[image]

What I'm doing wrong ?Is there any specific way for slidenavigationcontroller.Please anybody help to fix this.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:myColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

For more details ,you can refer following links :

1)[How to change UINavigationBar background color from the AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014713/how-to-change-uinavigationbar-background-color-from-the-app-delegate)

2)[Set background color for UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114583/set-background-color-for-uinavigationbar)

3)[Setting the background color of UINavigationBar has no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448020/setting-the-background-color-of-uinavigationbar-has-no-effect)